# How to create my own looper in android C++ instead of using Alooper class?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, message-queue, android-looper

I want to fully control the looper and message queue in android. Instead of using a looper class like this:

```
    ALooper *looper = ALooper_prepare(ALOOPER_PREPARE_ALLOW_NON_CALLBACKS);
```

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Regardless, did you read the source code for Looper to see what you would do differently?

Comment: I read the source code but it's belong to core android, so hard to understand and modify

Comment: Android source code tends to be only as complex as the problem it is solving. What do you hope to gain by reïmplementing it, and how _can_ you reïmplement it if you do not even understand the original system?